# How do I avoid the creation of root folder of the source in the destination when using rsync?

Tags: rsync

For example, when I copy all *.txt files in /tmp/src and its subfolders to /tmp/dst by

`rsync -avm --include='*.txt' --include='*/' --exclude='*' "/tmp/src" "/tmp/dst"`

it makes `src` under `/tmp/dst`.

but what I want is only the contents in /tmp/src.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply append a '/'. `/tmp/src/ /tmp/dst/`.

Comment: wdf! Simple and effective!!!